# Error with my database function create() in mysqli and php 7

Tags: php, mysqli

I was using PHP 5.6 and mysql 5.5, I updated to mysql 5.7 and php 7 for better speed (cause I heard php 7 is really faster than 5.6).

So I had this database function to insert my news rows on any table of my database.

```
public function create() {

        global $database;

        $attributes = $this -> sanitized_attributes();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO " . static::$table_name . " (";
        $sql.= join(", ",array_keys($attributes));
        $sql.= ") VALUES ('";
        $sql.= join("', '",array_values($attributes));
        $sql.= "')";

        if ( $database -> query($sql) ) {
          $this -> id = $database -> insert_id();
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        } // END - if ( $database -> query($sql) )

} // END - public function create()
```

now that I made the update and I try to check where the code is broken, I realized that I cannot enter any new row in any table.

I receive this error when I try to create a new row to any table:

> Database Query failed: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at
>   row 1

I somehow know where the problem is, my first cell on any table is an integer ID that is set to AUTO INCREMENT .. the problem at the function above is at this line I think:

```
$sql.= join("', '",array_values($attributes));
```

this first value is always an integer and PHP 7 and MYSQL 5.7 want the value withOUT the quotes. Thats what I realized .. when I was using the old PHP 5.3 - 5.6, the same database function never had a problem ..

Any solution how to fix this DATABASE function so I can escape the quotes just for the INTEGER VALUES and let the QUOTES for the STRING VALUES .. ???

Comment: please provide full sql string. `echo $sql;`
or if you have access to my.cnf - add this string `sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`

Comment: this the my sqli_error() that i receive every time that I tried to use the function create() - [code]Database Query failed: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1
Last SQL Query: INSERT INTO movies (id, html, movie_id, title, title_greek_check, main_poster, more_posters, more_backgrounds, actors, similar_movies, trailers, description, description_greek_check, info, views, time_update) VALUES ('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1472920502')[code]

Comment: Ok, it`s not bug - http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=18551, try: `unset($attributes['id']);` before ` $sql = "INSERT INTO "`, mysql 5.7 in strict mode by default

Comment: Thank you my friend it is ok now .. that was a good idea .. but I think I will have the same problem for any cell of any table that it is INTEGER.

Comment: Hm, after connect to db `$database->query('SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';')`;

Comment: You are awesome. That really helped, I do not know so much about my sql commands, just the basic to connect,read, write and update to databases .. I really wanted to start using PHP 7 .. I can realize even on my local enviroment that is faster .. thank you again for your help ..